# How to display category name from different table instead of category id

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have 2 tables - one [with forum category name field called "disp_name" and "ID" called "forum_cat"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA5Np.png)
and onother [with forum posts id, forum post content and cat_id and more  called "forum"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae3Se.png)

I have model "Forum_cats"

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Forum_cats extends Model
    {

    protected $table = 'forum_cat';

    public $timestamps = false;

    }
```

and model "Forum"

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model
{   

protected $table = 'forum';

public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Controller :

```
public function index(){


    $forum = Forum::orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')->paginate(20);

//next variable is for different place
    $news = Neww::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate(20);


    return view ('lapas.pamata.index',[
        'news'=>$news,
        'forum'=> $forum,
    ]);
}
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($forum as $forums)
          <li>
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-body"> <a href="#" class="catg_title"> 
              {{$forums->title}}</a> </div>
              <i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i>&nbsp;{{$forums->comments}} 
              Kategorija:{{$forums->cat_id}}
            </div>
          </li>
        @endforeach
```

so the view at the moment is [like this where after "Kategorija" i have only category id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iT2Q.png)

How to make after name "Kategorija" output field "disp_name" from table "forum_cat".

Someone can tell that there are lots of posts about my problem but i am trying to solve this problem all day. 
I know that its about hasOne, belongsTo and hasMany but i dont  understand how correct us them on my code.

Comment: Could you try to simplify? what would you like to display? (which field from which table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I assume (and still not sure) that forum belongs to a category.

Your Forum model should be:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model {   

    protected $table = 'forum';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public category(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum_cats', 'cat_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And your blade should be:

```
@foreach($forum as $forums)
          <li>
            <div class="media">
              <div class="media-body"> <a href="#" class="catg_title"> 
              {{$forums->title}}</a> </div>
              <i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i>&nbsp;{{$forums->comments}} 
              Kategorija:{{$forums->category->disp_name}}
            </div>
          </li>
@endforeach
```

does that work for you?
You also may consider eager loads:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads